# CPU start going crazy when starting to scroll the page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

here is the site.

https://stealth-wp-react.axon-media.com/

please some one help me with dignosing whats wrong with the javascript. when ever i scroll the page, computer's fans goes crazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the websites use a plugin or display a lot of graphics, they use more resources which cause the machine to heat up. That in turn will cause the fans to kick on.